# Facebook Image not Loading in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I'm loading Facebook images in my Android app, and it worked perfectly until this morning when I started getting:

```
SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

indicating that the image was not available. I checked it with an image from another url, and the code still works, so I figured Facebook must be having some trouble… does anyone know about this?

Here's the code I use:

```
URL img_value = null;
img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=" + type);
retval = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new BufferedInputStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that they redirect you with 302 to other url. 
It seems like your code doesn't handle that.

Maybe this will help: [Httpclient redirect handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131139/httpclient-redirect-handler)

Answer (score 1):

The same happened with my Android application.

I'm not sure because I cannot recall what was before but now this HTTP request is being redirected to HTTPS.

And Android [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) does support up to five redirects but not when there is HTTP <-> HTTPS change, I guess.

You could try to change http into https.
There is still a chance that FB will change this in the future again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution here:

[Getting null bitmap while trying to get Facebook image using Facebook ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681196/getting-null-bitmap-while-trying-to-get-facebook-image-using-facebook-id)

I would like to know what has changed..