# Facebook profile pictures are not visible in my android game anymore

Tags: android, facebook

I have an android game which users can login with facebook and play with their facebook friends. I am seeing a lot of comments about missing facebook profile pictures.

The below code does not work anymore. BitmapFactory.decodeStream returns null.
I am sure the url is correct, because till yesterday the app could display facebook profile pictures. What could have been changed?

Thanks.

`public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Failed to download image from " + src, e);
        return null;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It suddenly stopped working.. You can find a solution here:

[Getting null bitmap while trying to get Facebook image using Facebook ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681196/getting-null-bitmap-while-trying-to-get-facebook-image-using-facebook-id)

Comment: I've switched to DefaultHttpClient and profile pictures are visible. But i am trying to understand what has changed?

Comment: I think it's because the redirection that Facebook does. Using HttpURLConnection you get the redirection url, and not the picture.

Comment: Sorry, I really want to know what has changed and working method stopped working. Redirection is not a recent change I think.